# Uncheck other checkbox in a div when a single check box is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes under a div. How can I uncheck all the other check boxes when I am clicking on one input in this case?

Please help

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.pgggo-container-ajax-sorting').on('click', '.pgggo-list-taxon input', function() {
 alert("okay");
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pgggo-container-ajax-sorting">
<div class="pgggo-list-taxon">
<ul>
<li><label><label><input name="pgggo-category-sep-3[]" type="checkbox" /></label></label>
<div>
<div>Category 2</div>
</div>
</li>
<li><label><label><input name="pgggo-category-sep-4[]" type="checkbox" /></label></label>
<div>
<div>Category 3</div>
</div>
</li>
<li><label><label><input name="pgggo-category-sep-2[]" type="checkbox" /></label></label>
<div>
<div>Category1</div>
</div>
</li>
<li><label><label><input name="pgggo-category-sep-1[]" type="checkbox" /></label></label>
<div>
<div>Uncategorized</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `.not(this).prop('checked', false)` to remove checked from other checkboxes.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.pgggo-container-ajax-sorting').on('click', '.pgggo-list-taxon input', function() {
  //get checkboxes not this unchecked thm
  $(".pgggo-list-taxon").find("input[type=checkbox]").not(this)
    .prop('checked', false)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pgggo-container-ajax-sorting">
  <div class="pgggo-list-taxon">
    <ul>
      <li><label><label><input name="pgggo-category-sep-3[]" type="checkbox" /></label></label>
        <div>
          <div>Category 2</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><label><label><input name="pgggo-category-sep-4[]" type="checkbox" /></label></label>
        <div>
          <div>Category 3</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><label><label><input name="pgggo-category-sep-2[]" type="checkbox" /></label></label>
        <div>
          <div>Category1</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><label><label><input name="pgggo-category-sep-1[]" type="checkbox" /></label></label>
        <div>
          <div>Uncategorized</div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You know, the `checkbox` should be able to select multiple items. It's hard for users with that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a class called "pgggo" for each of the inputs, then use**

```
$('.pgggo').on('change', function() {
    if($(this)[0].checked)
            {$('.pgggo').not(this).prop('checked', false);  }
});
```

Here is some code that does what I hope you need
http://jsfiddle.net/EPEcono/vyh4Lcqu/4/